# How to set a selection of values in a pandas DataFrame with a selection from another pd.DataFrame using labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume 2 DataFrames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'], data=[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
df
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'], data=[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]], index=[3,4,5])
df1
   A  B  C
3  0  1  2
4  3  4  5
5  6  7  8
```

I want to set a part of df using values from df1 according to column-lables, without changing anithing in df but the selected fields. The desired result would be:

```
df

   A  B  C
0  4  5  2
1  7  8  5
2  6  7  8
```

I tried:

```
df.loc[df['A'].isin([0,3]), ['A', 'B']] = df1.loc[df1['A'].isin([7,6]), ['B', 'C']]
```

But the result is:

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  2.0
1  NaN  NaN  5.0
2  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

Because I guess it still requires the indices to match. I feel like this is a pretty basic task to do so I'm wondering if there is a simple way of ding this?
I also looked into 'merge' and 'join' but these functions seem to have different purpose.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution if matching number of rows and columns of both selections is convert output to mumpy array:

```
df.loc[df['A'].isin([0,3]), ['A', 'B']] = 
df1.loc[df1['A'].isin([3,6]), ['B', 'C']].to_numpy()
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  4  5  2
1  7  8  5
2  6  7  8
```